# Number of elements of order $2$ in $\mathbb Z_{60}\times \mathbb Z_{45}\times \mathbb Z_{12}\times \mathbb Z_{36}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

What is the number of elements of order $2$ in $\mathbb Z_{60}\times \mathbb Z_{45}\times \mathbb Z_{12}\times \mathbb Z_{36}$?

Are there any short formula to find the number of elements of a given order in a group of direct product of some groups?

Comment: I haven't done group theory in years but take a look at the following:

Note that

60 = 10*6 = 2*5*2*3 = 2^2*3*5
45 = 9*5 = 3^2*5
12 = 4*3 = 2^2*3
36 = 12*3 = 3*4*3 = 3^2*4.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**.  Using additive notation, you need to find elements $(a,b,c,d)$ of the group such that
$$2(a,b,c,d)=(0,0,0,0)\ .\tag{$*$}$$
That is,
$$2a\equiv0\pmod{60}\ ,\quad 2b\equiv0\pmod{45}$$
and so on.  So

- solve the congruences (or at least determine how many solutions there are);
- find how many quadruples satisfy $(*)$;
- decide whether any of these quadruples do not in fact have order $2$.

Good luck!