# Number of elements of order $12$ in $\mathbb{Z}_6 \times \mathbb{Z}_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Find the number of elements of order $12$ in $\mathbb{Z}_6 \times \mathbb{Z}_4$.

I got a hint saying there were $10$ but I don't understand how it works.

I know $(a,b)$ has to be the common multiple of $12$ i think.

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/953674/number-of-elements-of-order-2-in-mathbb-z-60-times-mathbb-z-45-times-m?rq=1) for how to find the number.

Comment: Any element of order $12$ generates a subgroup of order $12$. Any subgroup of order $12$ has four generators (if $g$ is one generator then the others are $g^5, g^7, g^{11}$). So the number of elements of order $12$ must be a multiple of $4$. In particular, the answer can't be $10$.

Comment: @amWhy why bring that into the picture?

Answer (score 2):

The order of an an element $(a, b) \in \Bbb{Z}_6 \times \Bbb{Z}_4$ is the least common multiple of the order of $a$ and the order of $b$.  (This is because $k(a, b) = (ka, kb)$ for $k = 1, 2, ...$.)  The possible orders of $a$ are $\{1, 2, 3, 6\}$, and the possible orders of $b$ are $\{1, 2, 4\}$.  From that, it's easy to see that the orders we're looking for must be 3 and 4, or 6 and 4.  And that gives you a list of 8 possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

> I know (a,b) has to be the common multiple of 12 i think.

If you mean that the order of $(a,b)$ will be the LCM of the two elements, and that you're looking for pairs such that the LCM is $12$, yes, that's a valid strategy.

However, I only see eight:
$(\pm 1, \pm 1), (\pm 2, \pm 1)$

When I do a complete tally of orders of element of the product, I get this table:

\begin{bmatrix}order&count\\
1&1\\2&3\\3&2\\4&4\\6&6\\12&8
\end{bmatrix}

Comment: $a$ order $6$ and $b$ order $2$ doesn't give order $12$.

Comment: @Arthur gah, yes... I got complacent when I got the number $10$ as indicated in the post. I'm having a hard time seeing why it is not just $8$ now...

Comment: I actually see just six: four of the form $(\pm1,\pm1)$ and two from $(3,\pm1)$. I might've missed some, though.

Comment: @Arthur $(\pm 2, \pm 1)$ and $(\pm 1,\pm 1)$!  $(3,\pm 1)$ all have order 4...